# How to Replace the path name of URL using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the url and load the page.

Example:

URL: http://www.example.com/account/edit

I want to replace this as http://www.example.com/account/add. And load this page.

For that, I tried by using location.pathname.

location.pathname = "/account/add";

When using like above, the add page is displayed. But after that, URL  http://www.example.com/account/add is loading. Then the add page is not displayed. I get that page is not found message.

The host name should vary based on running the project. So I want to resolve this without based on host name.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the page in your session history (meaning you want to be able to use the back button to it) use the **assign** method.  Otherwise, you **replace**.

> Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.location.html

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/account/add";
OR
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/account/add");
```

This will redirect to the new page.

Comment: The host name "www.example.com" should vary based on the project. So Cannot able to replace directly.

Comment: window.location.href(or replace) = '/account/add/'; should work fine too

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change your url some other ways like below:

```
window.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
```